# AWS Certificate Association

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, aws-acm

I missed the email advising me to renew my AWS certificate and am trying to disassociate it from my domain so I can delete it and get a new one. I installed and configured the Amazon CLI, but I cannot find documentation to disassociate the certificate.

I'm new to this and could use some help, specifically syntax to disassociate the certificate.

Comment: where is the certificate configured? a load balancer?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. I am using AWS CloudFront and simply changed the certificate from the AWS issued certificate to the default CloudFront certificate. I was then able to delete the certificate.

The certificate in question was not eligible for renewal.

Answer (score 1):

You never need to disassociate the certificate, you would instead create your new certificate and then replace its usage with whichever service you're using.

- For either a NLB or an ALB you would use the [modify-listener](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elbv2/modify-listener.html) command, specifying the arn of the SSL.
- For the classic load balancer you would use the [set-load-balancer-listener-ssl-certificate](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elb/set-load-balancer-listener-ssl-certificate.html)
- For a CloudFront distribution you would use the [update-distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html)
- For an API Gateway you would use [update-domain-name](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/apigateway/update-domain-name.html)

For CloudFront ensure your SSL is in `us-east-1`, otherwise create in the region of the resource you're attaching to.

It might also be worth for the future using the free ACM certificate as this will auto-renew.